# What does ダンッ mean?

Tags: translation, katakana, onomatopoeia

What does ダンッ mean in the following sentence from my book?

> 僕はナイフを投げかけた姿勢のまま、**ダンッ**と女の子に体当たりをかけた。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「ダンッ」 is an onomatopoeia (or sound effect) of bumping into something.. like "bump", "thud", "thump", similar to 「ドン」、「ドンッ」、「ドシン」...

Comment: What is the onomatopoeia dictionary that you use; if you do use one; as I'm having trouble with translating another sound effect. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/62354/what-does-the-onomonopia-ジワリと-mean

Comment: @Toyu_Frey 特に使ってないんですけど、オンラインで探しても、あんまりいいの見つからないですね・・　こんなのはどうでしょう：https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/japanese-onomatopoeia/ とか https://www.memrise.com/course/866287/1000-japanese-onomatopoeia/11/ とか http://thejadednetwork.com/sfx/search/?keyword=%E3%83%80%E3%83%B3%E3%83%83&submitSearch=Search+SFX&x= とか・・・？