# What does the onomatopoeia ジワリと mean?

Tags: translation, katakana, sound-symbolism

I tried going to my sound effect dictionary for this one but nothing came up, any help in figuring out what that bolded bit of the sentence means is much appreciated.

**ジワリ**と赤い血が滴り落ちる。

Comment: Have you tried ジワジワ instead?

Comment: これなんかどう？　https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%98%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8A%E3%81%A8/#je-37259

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **ジワリ**と赤い血が滴り落ちる。

ジワリ is an onomatopoeia of liquid (blood here) oozing out / coming out (of wound, eyes etc.) It can also describe liquid (slowly) soaking (into cloth/fabric). Its variants include: じわじわ, じんわり, じわっ.

These are close to ジワリ:

> じわっ   Liquids soaking and oozing
>   じんわり Soaking slowly with sweat or tears
>   (from https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/japanese-onomatopoeia/)

---

Quite a few onomatopoeiae have the same or similar pattern of variants, eg:

> - ふわふわ、ふわり、ふんわり、ふわっ、ふわん
> - きらきら、きらり、きらっ
> - ぴかぴか、ぴかり、ぴかっ
> - さらさら、さらり、さらっ
> - どきどき、どきり、どっきり、どきっ、どきん
> - ぱちぱち、ぱちり、ぱっちり、ぱちっ、ぱちん
> - つるつる、つるり、つるっ、つるん
>     etc...